# Set the alarm through the ical-Subscribe(Request type :Webcal) outlook calendar using C#

Tags: outlook, calendar, alarm, subscribe, reminders

When we import outlook Calendar through **Subscribe**(Request type: Webcal) all the events are created correctly and synchronizing works, but the VALARM is ignored and not set.

But if we **download**(text/calendar) generated ICS file and import into Outlook as a file then the VALARM (Reminder) works correctly.

Below is our code

```
        Event evt = iCal.Create<Event>();
        evt.Start = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(11));
        evt.End = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20));
        evt.Description = "test2";
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
        alarm.Action = AlarmAction.Display;
        alarm.Summary = "Alarm for the first Monday and second-to-last Monday of each month";
        alarm.Trigger = new Trigger(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-10)); 
        evt.Alarms.Add(alarm);

    iCalendarSerializer serializer = new iCalendarSerializer();
    string output = serializer.SerializeToString(iCal);
    Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
    Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=calendar.ics";
    Response.Write(output);
    Response.End();
```

Does anybody have an idea how to set the alarm through the ical-Subscribe(Request type :Webcal) outlook calendar?